# Is my pineapple plant dying?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care, tropical, pineapple

I noticed my pineapple plant was severely over-watered so I removed the wet soil, let my plant air dry out of the pot for a few days, then re-potted it with dry soil. But now its falling over, the leaves are curling, the tips of the leaves are starting to brown, and the stem appears to be dying/thinning out?

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

[image: Pineapple with browning lower leaves]

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is ok to over-water plants (once), for sure the pineapple should be able to cope with that (think about the weather they have on their native environments). Just you should be sure your pot as drainage holes on bottom (as any pots should have), so that excess water will flow away in reasonable time. Good soil choice will also help watering errors (more sand on soil which should be usually dry, more peat if soil must be wet). I think you overdid, by taking the pineapple away from soil for few days: that have more impact on roots compared to overwatering once.

But your photo, to me, shows a different thing. Do you see that on bottom of the "dry" part there are new leaves? And on top you have different leaves (but also not so long)? And not much leaves scars on the elongated stem? Maybe you over-watered the pineapple because the top were brown, right? In my opinion, your pineapple was having the little pineapple. You see the aborted pineapple above the elongated steam (which the pineapple do when they are flowering).

In my opinion, the top part is the new pineapple (but without the seeds and without the fruit). Now the stem between the old and the new pineapple should elongate more (and curve more), then you can plant the new "pineapple" (really you do not have the fruit, but only the top part of the new pineapple). Note: I may notice one or two flowers (which may seems leave scars).

In my experience (but just with few fruits, and none this year) the bottom part will die, but you may get few vegetative shots on the bottom.

Comment: So what would you recommend I do? Leave the old pineapple for now, or should I remove it?

Comment: Do you mean "the new pineapple"? Leave it until it curves too much (or the stem is dry and death). Lets the mother to provide as much energy as possibly to the new plant. Then plant the new pineapple as you would with the top of a regular fruit.